# Windows 10 : how to share internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, cmd.exe, windows-10, internet-sharing, virtual-wifi

Since yesterday i started using Windows 10, after that i cant share my laptop's internet :( i need to share my laptop internet(internet dongle) to my tablet and phone, had used "virtualrouterplus" and "mhotspot" software both doesn't work in windows 10 now. tried these commands in cmd

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Hotspot key=asd123qwe
```

and

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

and changed few settings in Network and Sharing Center for internet sharing, still cant share let me know if commands or software

Comment: Try the steps here: [How To Turn Your Windows 8.1 Or Windows 10 Device Into A WiFi Access Point](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-turn-your-windows-81-laptop-wifi-access-point)

Comment: @MC10 tried same thing, nothing